# Cannot change Stylecop-Settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, stylecop

I try to setup Stylecop-Settings for my projects inside VS2015. When I open the settings using RMB on my project name I receive the following error:
[image]
[image]

I started VS with admin rights, Styecop itself is a fresh installation (installed yesterday) and works as expected. Just configuration does not work.

Comment: I also have this same issue, has anyone got a solution for this? I have just done fresh install of VS2015, Resharper 10 and Stylecop by Resharper plugin, everything works except stylecop settings

Comment: If you got the same problem, upvoting the question might help :)

Comment: StyleCop 4.7.50 (VS2015 support) is an alpha release, so it may be worth raising on their [project page](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/).